# How to get latest value from table with self inner join

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, join

Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9254d/3/0

I have two tables, Person and Values, PersonID is the link between them. Each person in the Values table has multiple values per day for every hour. I need to get the latest value for each user. I had a look on SO and what I could find was to get MAX(ValueDate) and then join on that but doesn't work. Join on PersonID didn't work either, not sure what else to try.

The output I need is

```
Name       Value
1fn 1ln      2
2fn 2ln      20
3fn 3ln      200
```

I don't need the greatest value, I need the latest value for each person. Please share if you have any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9254d/9)**

```
DECLARE @Org nvarchar(3)
SELECT @Org = 'aaa'

DECLARE @MyDate date
SELECT @MyDate = CONVERT(date, '2014-09-12')

SELECT a.Name,
       a.Value as Revenue
FROM(
SELECT p.FName + ' ' + p.LName AS Name,
vt.Value,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY vt.PersonID ORDER BY vt.ValueDate desc) as rnk
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN ValueTable vt
  ON vt.PersonID = p.PersonID
WHERE vt.ValueDate < DATEADD(day,1,@MyDate)
AND vt.ValueDate >= @MyDate
AND vt.Org = @Org)a
WHERE a.rnk = 1
ORDER BY a.Name ASC
```

Result:

```
|    NAME | REVENUE |
|---------|---------|
| 1fn 1ln |       2 |
| 2fn 2ln |      20 |
| 3fn 3ln |     200 |
```